# Mapping Array of Objects in ReactJS to create login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom

Im currently trying to create a login form in ReactJS (which does not have any backend and is relying on a Users.js file for input.

My App.js looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import myUser from './User'

import './App.css';


class App extends React.Component{

constructor(){


super()
this.state={userName:"",password:"",message:false} //myUser:[]
this.eventHandler=this.eventHandler.bind(this)
this.postDetails=this.postDetails.bind(this)
}

eventHandler(event){

const {name,value}=event.target



this.setState({[name]:value})


}

postDetails(event){
 
event.preventDefault()
return(this.state.userName===myUser.name&&this.state.password===myUser.password? 
this.setState({message:true}):this.setState({message:false}))

}



render(){
return(
  <div className="main-div">
    <h1>{this.state.message===true?"Success":"Try again"}</h1>
    <form>
     
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter name" name="userName"  onChange={this.eventHandler} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="password" placeholder="enter password" name="password"  onChange={this.eventHandler} />
      <br />
      <br/>
      <button value="submit" onClick={this.postDetails}>Submit</button>

    </form>
  
   
  </div>



)
}
}

export default App;
```

and my User.js looks something like this:

```
const users ={id:1,name:"mahesh",password:"mahesh123"}



export default users
```

So the above code only check whether the username and password fields entered in the form match the name and password of single record in the array of objects of User.js
the above code is working fine. But what if I wanted to make an array of objects , supposing:

```
const users =[{id:1,name:"mahesh",password:"mahesh123"},{id:2,name:"abc",password:"abc123"}]
```

and wanted to compare for multiple records? Do i have to use mapping? Please show an instance of how it is done. Please help , i'm fairly new to React. My apologies for the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting accustomed with most common array prototype methods ( like [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ) would help a lot with solving those kinds of problems.

```js
export const users = [
    { id: 0, name: 'user1', password: 'asd1' },
    { id: 0, name: 'user2', password: 'asd2' },
    { id: 0, name: 'user3', password: 'asd3' },
];
```

Then your `postDetails` would need to look like this:

```js
import { users } from '...';

// ...

postDetails() {
    const isUserValid = users.some(user => {
        const username = this.state.userName;
        const password = this.state.password;
        return user.name === username && user.password === password;
    });
    this.setState({ message: isUserValid });
};
```

Comment: Hello Sir , thank you for your response , i implemented your code and i get the following error: TypeError: _User__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.some is not a function

Comment: `users` needs to be an array, instead of exporting is as default, change it to a named export. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is the functhion which try to find a user first and then if we find object with same name we check the password. If something isn't valid the function returns false otherwise it returns true

```js
const users =[
  {id:1,name:"mahesh",password:"mahesh123"},
  {id:2,name:"abc",password:"abc123"}
]

const validation = (login, password) => {
  const user = users.find(user => login === user.name) // find the user with same name
  if (typeof user !== 'undefined') { // check the user. If we didn't find a object with same name, user will be undefined 
    return user.password === password // if passwords match it returns true
  }
  return false
}

console.log(validation('mahesh', 'mahesh123'))
console.log(validation('abc', 'abc123'))
console.log(validation('abc', 'sffh'))
console.log(validation('abdsawec', 'abc123'))
```