# Form Validation React Native

Tags: react-native, create-react-app

Actually i am making a simple login app using react native, in which valid usernames and password stored in an array now if the user enter input for username and password how to check from that array and if its a match grant access else error.

here is a link for my snack - https://snack.expo.dev/@gauravkalota/full-assignment-23-august

Comment: what do you use for the backend?

Comment: sir it is a simple login app in which i am storing array for valid username and password and now i want that if the user login with those credentials can login else fail

Comment: Where do you store user credentials ?

Comment: @LakpriyaSenevirathna sir i want to create an array in which i will store my username and password credentials .

Comment: @LakpriyaSenevirathna like this :-  var customer= ["John", "Mary", "Doe"] && var pin = [1452, 7858, 2016]

Comment: I think this could be starting point - https://stackoverflow.com/a/63130443/3238940

Answer (score 0):

store username and password credentials. You can used https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/async-storage/ if working with expo or https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage to store your login creditial and can be access from any page